# problem while importing the data from text to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, text, import, load-data-infile

I have used an application to import some data from a text file to mysql. I have used the following code.

```
try
{
   stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                               ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
   stmt1= (Statement) conn.createStatement();
   int deleteRows = stmt1.executeUpdate("delete  from powerdata where dateformat < dateformat_sub(now(), interval 8 month)");
   query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \"E:\\powerdata.txt\" INTO TABLE powerdata  set dateformat=str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y' '%H:%i:%s');";
   int Update= stmt.executeUpdate(query);
}
```

But the query to load the data from text to mysql is null. Can anybody tell me where I have made a mistake?

Comment: This code fragment appears to be missing useful context, such as the types of stmt, stmt1, query, etc; I'll wager they're something like Statement, Statement and String, but it's not obvious. Can you also rephrase the actual problem, with reference to your code if necessary?

Comment: i have given only try block and not the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the problem is the `\"E:\\powerdata.txt\"` bit? You're escaping the quotes, but you're not escaping the backslashes. That means your query actually looks like this:
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "E:\powerdata.txt" INTO TABLE powerdata  set dateformat=str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y' '%H:%i:%s');

To fix the filename, use `\"E:\\\\powerdata.txt\"`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't given the user you are using [FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privileges. If you look over the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) they talk about the privileges a remote user would need to load data using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. There is a good reason this is turned off so be careful if you enable it.

Comment: i have executed the cmd sucessfully in mysql. The problem is that i am using the java application to do this and there i am having the problem